# G++ -M32 -M64 switches on Windows

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks, gcc4.7

How can I install gcc 4.7.2 for codeblocks that supports both 32 and 64 compilation?

If I install the x32 bit compiler: x32-4.7.2-release-win32-sjlj-rev10
it will compile with -m32 but give a bunch of linker errors for -m64

If I install the x64 bit compiler: x64-4.7.2-release-win32-sjlj-rev10
it will compile with -m64 but give a bunch of linker errors for -m32

Both from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/

So again, how can I get my Mingw or Gcc to be able to compile for both using the -m switch?

I'm using Windows 8 Pro x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a makefile, I was able to compile with -m32 and -m64.

So I figured there has to be a way to do this in Codeblocks.
I did the following:

CompilerSettings->Other options  and added -m32

Then in Linker Settings under other linker options I added -m32

I only had the x64 compiler installed. It has lib32 folder included in it so that's why this works.

It compiled both a 32 and 64 bit dll. Tested both on two different machines and the x64 does not load on the 32bit machine. :) 32 on the other hand loads on both.